# SonarQube Sonar.exclusions parameter is not working from jenkins and from SonarQube server

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

sonar.exclusions parameter is not working for Sonarqube, the sonar.exclusions parameter defined in Jenkins or project setting in SonarQube Server it is not taking effect and scanning all files.

I want to exclude CSS,JS and HTML file scanning from the project for that I defined

```
sonar.exclusions=**/*.css, **/*.js ,**/*.html
```

also defined the path with root path with Jenkins workspace like
`sonar.exclusions=$WORKSPACE/src/**/*.css, $WORKSPACE/src/**/*.js`
still no positive result .

Also defined exclusions in sonarQube sever also

[image]

```
Software Stack

SonarQube:7.9.4-community 
Jenkins: 2.235.1 
Jenkins-plugin: SonarQubeScanner for Jenkins 2.11 
SonarQube Scanner:- 3.0.0.702
```

The Jenkins console output is the following . what mistake I am making here can someone guide me?

```
Dsonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=/opt/cloudhost/apps/.jenkins/workspace/TEMP_SONARQUBE_CI_CD_LEMS_BUILD_EXTRA/build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml 
Dsonar.sources=/opt/cloudhost/apps/.jenkins/workspace/TEMP_SONARQUBE_CI_CD_LEMS_BUILD_EXTRA/src 
Dsonar.surefire.reportsPath=/opt/cloudhost/apps/.jenkins/workspace/TEMP_SONARQUBE_CI_CD_LEMS_BUILD_EXTRA/
build/test-results/test "-Dsonar.exclusions=**/*.css, **/*.js , **/*.html" -Dsonar.projectVersion=Octane-137020-SonarQube-Integrations -
Dsonar.java.binaries=/opt/cloudhost/apps/.jenkins/workspace/TEMP_SONARQUBE_CI_CD_LEMS_BUILD_EXTRA/build/c
lasses -Dsonar.projectKey=LEMS_X_Exclude -
Dsonar.junit.reportPaths=/opt/cloudhost/apps/.jenkins/workspace/TEMP_SONARQUBE_CI_CD_LEMS_BUILD_EXTRA/bui
ld/test-results/test 
Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/opt/cloudhost/apps/.jenkins/workspace/TEMP_SONARQUBE_CI_CD_LEMS_BUILD_EXTRA
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /opt/cloudhost/apps/.jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/SonarQubeScanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties


INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.0.0.702
INFO: Java 1.8.0_252 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 3.10.0-1127.10.1.el7.x86_64 amd64
INFO: User cache: /home/stlpdapi/.sonar/cache
INFO: SonarQube server 7.9.4
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
WARN: SonarScanner will require Java 11 to run starting in SonarQube 8.x
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=119ms
INFO: Server id: E2281BAA-AXPWxgc9dGdpV1spT8iU
INFO: User cache: /home/stlpdapi/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load/download plugins
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=79ms
INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=134ms
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Execute project builders
INFO: Execute project builders (done) | time=3ms
INFO: Project key: LEMS_X_Exclude
INFO: Base dir: /opt/cloudhost/apps/.jenkins/workspace/TEMP_SONARQUBE_CI_CD_LEMS_BUILD_EXTRA
INFO: Working dir: /opt/cloudhost/apps/.jenkins/workspace/TEMP_SONARQUBE_CI_CD_LEMS_BUILD_EXTRA/.scannerwork
INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'LEMS_X_Exclude'
INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'LEMS_X_Exclude' (done) | time=22ms
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=75ms
INFO: Detected Jenkins
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=747ms
INFO: Indexing files...
INFO: Project configuration:
INFO:   Excluded sources: **/*.css, **/*.js, **/*.html
INFO: Load project repositories
INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=44ms
INFO: 1221 files indexed
INFO: 0 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
INFO: 0 files ignored because of scm ignore settings
INFO: Quality profile for css: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for java: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for jsp: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for xml: Sonar way
INFO: ------------- Run sensors on module LEMS_X_Exclude
INFO: Load metrics repository
INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=25ms
INFO: Sensor JavaSquidSensor [java]
INFO: Configured Java source version (sonar.java.source): none
INFO: JavaClasspath initialization
WARN: Bytecode of dependencies was not provided for analysis of source files, you might end up with less precise results. Bytecode can be provided using sonar.java.libraries property.
INFO: JavaClasspath initialization (done) | time=12ms
INFO: JavaTestClasspath initialization
INFO: JavaTestClasspath initialization (done) | time=2ms
INFO: Java Main Files AST scan
INFO: 405 source files to be analyzed
INFO: 28/405 files analyzed, current file: src/main/java/com/mf/pdapi/orm/pojo/SoftwareLicenseStructure.java
INFO: 100/405 files analyzed, current file: src/main/java/com/mf/pdapi/services/pdapi/mappers/response/APGetEntitlementResponseMapper.java
INFO: 168/405 files analyzed, current file: src/main/java/com/mf/pdapi/web/controller/IndexController.java
INFO: 206/405 files analyzed, current file: src/main/java/com/mf/pdapi/web/controller/licensePanination/LicenseController.java
INFO: 258/405 files analyzed, current file: src/main/java/com/mf/pdapi/web/models/ProductVO.java
WARN: Invalid character encountered in file /opt/cloudhost/apps/.jenkins/workspace/TEMP_SONARQUBE_CI_CD_LEMS_BUILD_EXTRA/src/test/java/com/mf/pdapi/services/utils/SecurityHelperUtilTest.java at line 34 for encoding UTF-8. Please fix file content or configure the encoding to be used using property 'sonar.sourceEncoding'.
INFO: 405/405 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Java Main Files AST scan (done) | time=57784ms
INFO: Java Test Files AST scan
INFO: 0 source files to be analyzed
INFO: Java Test Files AST scan (done) | time=2ms
INFO: 0/0 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Sensor JavaSquidSensor [java] (done) | time=58443ms
INFO: Sensor SonarCSS Metrics [cssfamily]
INFO: Sensor SonarCSS Metrics [cssfamily] (done) | time=125ms
INFO: Sensor SonarCSS Rules [cssfamily]
ERROR: CSS rules were not executed. Error when running: 'node -v'. Is Node.js available during analysis?
org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandException: Error when running: 'node -v'. Is Node.js available during analysis?
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommand.start(NodeCommand.java:83)
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandBuilderImpl.getVersion(NodeCommandBuilderImpl.java:196)
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandBuilderImpl.checkNodeCompatibility(NodeCommandBuilderImpl.java:169)
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandBuilderImpl.build(NodeCommandBuilderImpl.java:144)
    at org.sonar.css.plugin.server.CssAnalyzerBridgeServer.initNodeCommand(CssAnalyzerBridgeServer.java:133)
    at org.sonar.css.plugin.server.CssAnalyzerBridgeServer.startServer(CssAnalyzerBridgeServer.java:101)
    at org.sonar.css.plugin.server.CssAnalyzerBridgeServer.startServerLazily(CssAnalyzerBridgeServer.java:153)
    at org.sonar.css.plugin.CssRuleSensor.execute(CssRuleSensor.java:99)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse(AbstractSensorWrapper.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:85)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.withModuleStrategy(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:77)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:82)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:400)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:395)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:358)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:141)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:73)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:99)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:123)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:77)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommand$ProcessWrapperImpl.start(NodeCommand.java:175)
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommand.start(NodeCommand.java:79)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 39 common frames omitted

INFO: Sensor SonarCSS Rules [cssfamily] (done) | time=938ms
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
INFO: Importing 1 report(s). Turn your logs in debug mode in order to see the exhaustive list.
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=253ms
INFO: Sensor SurefireSensor [java]
INFO: parsing [/opt/cloudhost/apps/.jenkins/workspace/TEMP_SONARQUBE_CI_CD_LEMS_BUILD_EXTRA/build/test-results/test]
INFO: Sensor SurefireSensor [java] (done) | time=35ms
INFO: Sensor JaCoCoSensor [java]
INFO: Sensor JaCoCoSensor [java] (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java]
INFO: 41 source files to be analyzed
INFO: Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java] (done) | time=526ms
INFO: Sensor HTML [web]
INFO: 41/41 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Sensor HTML [web] (done) | time=1841ms
INFO: Sensor XML Sensor [xml]
INFO: 52 source files to be analyzed
INFO: Sensor XML Sensor [xml] (done) | time=562ms
INFO: 52/52 source files have been analyzed
INFO: ------------- Run sensors on project
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=22ms
INFO: Sensor Java CPD Block Indexer
INFO: Sensor Java CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=640ms
INFO: 78 files had no CPD blocks
INFO: Calculating CPD for 427 files
INFO: CPD calculation finished
INFO: Analysis report generated in 378ms, dir size=9 MB
INFO: Analysis report compressed in 1574ms, zip size=3 MB
INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 263ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is:

```
ERROR: CSS rules were not executed. Error when running: 'node -v'. Is Node.js available during analysis?
```

It means what you do not have nodejs installed. Just configure it in jenkins global tools menu, add it to your job and run it again.

Comment: I am trying to achieve  skip the CSS, Html, js files from sonarQube scanning. for the same i defined the following parameter like 
sonar.exclusions=**/.css, **/.js , **/.html*